# Django: dictsort not working with integer field

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have this field in one of my models

```
    sort_id = models.IntegerField(_('Sort Order'), default=1000)
```

In my template, I'm trying to use this field to sort a list

```
   {% for item in list|dictsort:"sort_id" %}
```

However, the for loop outputs nothing in that case (but doesn't raise any errors either). If I use another model field as argument for dictsort, the output is not empty and sorted as expected.

Comment: Are you running this in template_debug mode? Since templates silently ignore errors otherwise.
Also, what does list look like? Better, can you show the view code that creates list?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/W961qpaw I'm extending the stock flatpages model. Template debug is True, and the output is an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had not redefined the "get_flatpages" tag to point to my own model, so I was getting the stock Django flatpages (that don't have my custom fields). Changing the template tag definition fixed it.